# Kernel panic: unable to mount root fs on an unknown block

Tags: ubuntu, boot

[image]
I had upgraded Ubuntu 16.04 to 17.04 .after a while I had restarted my laptop and when it was about to restart  my battery was dead and I plugged in th charger and power on my laptop and it shows a command as above picture

Answer (score 4):

This happens because it is missing the initramfs for that kernel.

Start with a live USB/CD, choose 'Try Ubuntu' and open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

1. List your partitions with `sudo fdisk -l` and choose the right one to mount:

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt
   ```

   Where `sdX` is your Ubuntu installation on your HDD. If you have an EFI boot system you need to mount your EFI partition as well.

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sdY /mnt/boot/efi
   ```

   Where `sdY` is your EFI partition.
2. Now mount the following and chroot into your install

   ```
   sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
   sudo mount -o bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
   sudo mount -t sysfs /sys /mnt/sys
   sudo mount -t proc /proc /mnt/proc
   sudo chroot /mnt
   ```
3. Create a `update-initramfs` and `update-grub`. Make sure you put the right version number into the next line, you can find this by `dpkg --list | grep linux-image` or `ls /lib/modules/` .

   ```
   update-initramfs -u -k 4.10.0-38-generic
   update-grub
   ```
4. Unmount and reboot your system.

   ```
   exit
   sudo umount /mnt/boot/efi
   sudo umount /mnt
   ```

> If you get `umount: /mnt: target is busy.` you can try this:

```
    umount /mnt/proc
    umount /mnt/sys
    umount /mnt/dev/pts
    umount /mnt/dev
    umount /mnt
```

5. Reboot your system

   ```
   reboot
   ```

Comment: Is it Sudo fdisk-1

Comment: Its an lowercase L.

Comment: This chroot works only for bios-installation. Besides such a distro-upgrade is not backed. You omit Ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: If you get to grub can you drop to a grub shell (press `c` at the grub menu)?

Comment: If you get to grub yes, you could drop into grub shell, but not sure if that will help, you can as well try to boot the older systems kernel which might or might not work.

Comment: @Bahamut What makes you think `chroot` was somehow related to UEFI? The `update-grub` command might be different for a UEFI system.

Comment: @Hauke Laging. You have to mount efi-boot-partition too.  `mount /dev/sdxY /mnt/boot/efi`  Grub2 mußt write his /bootgrub/grub.cfg somewhere.

Comment: @Bahamut see, I use still legacy system, if you would have commented this directly I could have improved my answer directly :) and not wondering what now is wrong.